# Connecting to sql server data with PHP on ubuntu

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, freetds

When trying to connect to my mssql database, I get the error 
    "SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)"

Below is the php code I'm running

```
<?php

  try {
    $hostname = "hostname.database.windows.net";
    $port = 1433;
    $dbname = "database-dev";
    $username = "dbuser";
    $pw = "dbpassword";   
    $dbh = new PDO     ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select name from master..sysdatabases where     name = db_name()");
  $stmt->execute();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }  
  unset($dbh); unset($stmt);
?>
```

And below is my odbc.ini, odbcinst.ini and freetds.conf, you can see my phpinfo() here ("http://wingedw.com/matiks/connect.php") the driver is set to freetds and the pdo and pdo_dlib modules have been added to php 5, any clues as to why im getting error, im sure the credentials are right.

odbc.ini

```
[MSSQLServer]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = Any description
Trace = No
Server = servername
Port = 1433
Database = dbname
wTDS_Verison = 7.1
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Driver      = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount      = 1
```

freetds.conf

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
;       tds version = 7.1

    # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
    # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

    # Command and connection timeouts
;       timeout = 100
;       connect timeout = 100

    # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
    # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  
    # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit 
    text size = 64512

# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
    host = symachine.domain.com
    port = 5000
    tds version = 7.1

# A typical Microsoft server
[MSSQLServer]
    host = servername
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.1
```

Comment: In your `odbc.ini`, you seem to have `wTDS_Verison = 7.1` instead of `TDS_Verison = 7.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out everything was configured correctly, the issue was using dblib over odbc, see code below.

```
try {
    $hostname = "hostname.database.windows.net";
    $port = 1433;
    $dbName = "databasename";
    $dbuser = "dbuser@hostname";
    $dbpass = "password";   
$dbh = new PDO('odbc:DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVERNAME=mssql;DATABASE=' . $dbName,
          $dbuser, $dbpass);
  //echo "COnnected";

  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

### 2021 - BACK TO THE FUTURE:

I know that this post is old, but my reply can point a desperate soul in the right direction:

1. You are using odbc and the command "isql" works just fine
2. You are using FreeTDS and the command "tsql" works just fine
3. Trouble is running the php scripts that have calls to odbc via FreeTDS -> keeps giving errors

Kindly read:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/tix-592494/freettds-libiodbc-iodbc-php-7-4-21-on-slackware-current-5-13-5-38621/

Cheers happy souls!